# How to install QtRuby + Qt4 on Ubuntu 14?

Tags: ruby, qt-creator, qt4

I wish to program in ruby in QtCreator. If I'm right, I need to install QtRuby + Qt4, but with no success on Ubuntu 14. How to do? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these steps to install Qtruby+Qt4

run following command in terminal

`sudo aptitude install libqt4-core libqt4-dev`

Download qtruby from http://rubyforge.org/projects/korundum/

```
version=2.1.0
wget http://rubyforge.org/frs/download.php/71843/qt4-qtruby-${version}.tar.gz
```

Extract qtruby

```
tar -xvzf qt4-qtruby-${version}.tar.gz
cd qt4-qtruby-${version}
```

qtruby installer uses the location of the Ruby binary it is started with

```
rvm use 1.8.7
cmake .
make
```

Now install,

```
sudo make install
```

ubuntu doesn't look here by default, but the qtruby install puts its libraries here

```
sudo ldconfig /usr/local/lib
```

We had to run make install with root because it writes to /usr/local/lib, but it also writes to $MY_RUBY_HOME.

we don't want root-owned files floating around in there

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER $MY_RUBY_HOME
```

**NOTE** - For more information please have a look at [rvm documentation](https://rvm.io/integration/qtruby)

Comment: The link for rubyforge no longer works